# Problem using tool panel in inkscape

Tags: 16.04, inkscape

When I click on the buttons next to the digital input several times, They are froze, as if I continue to hold mouse button. This is screencast:

[image: The problem]

I use Ubuntu Gnome 16.04. Can I fix this?

Comment: I found bug about it: https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/1164150

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed in Ubuntu 18.04